# is Lucene boolean OR queries scoring biased towards the term having more alternatives

Tags: solr, lucene, boolean

Why Lucene/Solr scorer is making a sum of the weight of the OR clauses. It is unbalancing the query scoring toward the term that has more alternatives. Wouldn't it make more sense to have the max of the weight of query term alternatives ?

Here is an example:

I ran in the solr admin interface: gucci (handbag OR purse OR pocketbook)

By clicking debug I can see that the parsed query is as expected:

```
"parsedquery":"text:gucci (text:handbag text:purse text:pocketbook)"
```

The explain field shows that the scorer is making (I simplify a bit here):

```
weight(gucci) + sum( weight(handbag) + weight(purse) + weight(pocketbook))
```

The consequence is that a result containing handbag, purse and pocketbook is going to have a higher score than a result containing gucci and handbag. I think this is counter-intuitive. To me the OR means those terms are equivalent, not that they are more important. Besides I could use query term boosting to do this independently.

I experimented with Edismax and it has similar behaviour.

Is there a way to have an OR clause which preserve query term "importance" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `DisjunctionMaxQuery` and set different boost factors for disjuncts. Have a look at the `tieBreakMultiplier` constructor parameter - it can help to achieve what you want. Quoting the documentation:

> tieBreakerMultiplier <..> value <..> says that 10 occurrences of word in a lower-scored field that 
>   is also in a higher scored field is just as good as a unique word in the lower scored field

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it looks like this is a disjunction over fields, in my case I would like this disjunction over parts of the query so that for a single field "text" for example: score=weight(A)+max(weight(B),weight(B1)) or max(weight(A)+weight(B),weight(A)+weight(B1)) (B1 being synonym of B)